# React Context API and/or React-Redux-Thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, store

Im using Context API for multi store management and React-Redux with thunk for a single store management.

Should I stick to one over the other or should I use React-Redux for multiple store management over React's Context API.

I spoke with a friend who did vice-versa versus me for his company and im wondering why but never got an explanation.

Whats the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

React Context API is somewhat harder to manage you can use `redux` instead to manage states.
`react-redux` is just used as a connector between `react` and `redux`.

You can do the following for best practices:

- For multi store management you can go for `redux`.
- For connecting `react` with `redux` you can go for `react-redux`.
- For middle ware you can either go for `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`.

I prefer `redux-saga` as it has more advantages over `redux-thunk`.

Answer (score 0):

Redux was and still is very popular for large applications where you need to be able to maintain a single source of truth but pass down different parts of the store as props to various components. The advantage of this package is that it can make debugging easier and if implemented correctly is very robust.

As far as redux middleware goes, they are generally used for asynchronous integration. Thunk and Saga are two popular libraries. Context should be able to handle async without any other dependencies.

Context API is a newer feature released as part of React 16.3 and allows for easier store creation but, in my opinion, can be more difficult to scale. I don't have as much experience using Context API but it has become very popular and for an experienced developer can do anything redux does.

I would say it is generally discouraged to use both when one approach would work just as well. That being said, an application I manage uses both, because when it was first created Context API 16.3 had not yet been released so redux was the only state manager for the whole app, but later some localized component states were updated to have their own context store. I don't think this is the best practice, however.

Read more about the technical differences [here](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-context-replaces-redux/).

Answer (score 0):

One of the best and most overlooked alternatives to `Redux` is to use `React's` own built-in `Context API`.

`Context API` provides a different approach to tackling the data flow problem between `React’s` deeply nested components. Context has been around with `React` for quite a while, but it has changed significantly since its inception. Up to version 16.3, it was a way to handle the state data outside the `React` component tree. It was an experimental feature not recommended for most use cases.

Initially, the problem with legacy context was that updates to values that were passed down with context could be “blocked” if a component skipped rendering through the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method. Since many components relied on `shouldComponentUpdate` for performance optimizations, the legacy context was useless for passing down plain data.

The new version of `Context API` is a dependency injection mechanism that allows passing data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

The most important thing here is that, unlike `Redux`, `Context API` is not a state management system. Instead, it’s a dependency injection mechanism where you manage a state in a `React` component. We get a state management system when using it with `useContext` and `useReducer` hooks.

If an application isn't overly complex, it is highly preferable to use the built-in `Content API` over adding another library that adds unnecessary complexity. Remember - most states do not need to be global.

A great next step to learning more is to read this article by Andy Fernandez: https://www.scalablepath.com/react/context-api-vs-redux